# How do i write my erb file without skipping lines

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

i have the t function witch return some text.

so on my erb file i have something like that:

```
<%= t 'content1' %> 
<%= t 'content2' %>
```

and the html output is something like that:

```
"text of the content 1"
"text of the content 2"
```

I would like to output something like that:

```
"text of the content 1" "text of the content 2"
```

thanx

Comment: `so on my erb file i have something like that`, like that what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERB has an option in the closing tag whether to have a newline after it. Just add a dash:

```
<%= t 'content1' -%> 
<%= t 'content2' %>
```

Comment: worked like a charme thx! Is there a way to do the same but with a blanc space as opposite to the line?

Comment: No, but in that case you can do `<% %> <% %>`

Answer (score 1):

Erb is a little overrated compared to other template languages out there. But, the good thing is it allows you to control the output. As @DMG pointed out add a '-' to your tags but there is also another point I wanted to show.

```
<%- method(...) -%>
```

Will not show any lines on output. While this will create a blank line:

```
<% method(...) -%>
```

Just something to keep in mind if your writing templates for scripts, unit tests, rake task, or anything else outside of Rails/ActionView

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
<%= "#{t('content1')}#{t('content2')}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= "#{t('content1')} #{t('content2')}" %>
```